# wordpress pagination doesn't show

Tags: wordpress, pagination

******EDIT*******

This is now my code for posts:

```
<?php
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); }
elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { $paged = get_query_var('page'); }
else { $paged = 1; }
query_posts('posts_per_page=3&paged=' . $paged);
  $args = array (
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    $offset = $paged*$pages,
    'post_type' => array('post','project'),
    'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id'
  );
```

The navigation with numbers show, and he goes to page/2 but the new posts didn't show.

---

I build an local Wordpress website for an test. I add pagination in Wordpress. But the Pagination don't show up. This is my code:

```
 $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $args = array (
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'offset' => 0,
    'post_type' => array('post','project'),
    'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id',
    'paged' => $paged
  )

  $home_recent = new WP_Query( $args );
  if( $home_recent ->have_posts() ) :
  while( $home_recent ->have_posts() ) :
  $home_recent ->the_post();
  $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' ); 
  $post_type = get_post_type( $post->ID ); ?>
```

This if for get posts.

This my function:

```
 function pagination($pages = '', $range = 4)
 {  
 $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  

 global $paged;
 if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

 if($pages == '')
 {
     global $wp_query;
     $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
     if(!$pages)
     {
         $pages = 1;
     }
 }   

 if(1 != $pages)
 {
     echo "<div class=\"pagination\"><span>Page ".$paged." of ".$pages."</span>";
     if($paged > 2 && $paged > $range+1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link(1)."'>&laquo; First</a>";
     if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>&lsaquo; Previous</a>";

     for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++)
     {
         if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems ))
         {
             echo ($paged == $i)? "<span class=\"current\">".$i."</span>":"<a href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class=\"inactive\">".$i."</a>";
         }
     }

     if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href=\"".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."\">Next &rsaquo;</a>";  
     if ($paged < $pages-1 &&  $paged+$range-1 < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<a href='".get_pagenum_link($pages)."'>Last &raquo;</a>";
     echo "</div>\n";
 }
  }
```

And this for show the pagination:

```
  <?php }
  endwhile;
  if (function_exists("pagination")) {
  pagination($additional_loop->max_num_pages);
  } 

  endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Butt It shows nothing only the three posts. Is this code wrong or miss I things?

Julian

Comment: Why not use wordpress function paginate_links? @Julian Rouw

Comment: Because this works with numbers. I've already got some more work, he shows the page numbers and I can click on it but he keeps on page 1 show. I added this piece of code: query_posts('showposts=3&paged='. $paged);

Comment: there is a argument prev_next, if you make it false it will only show numbered pagination @Julian Rouw

Comment: I have now that the navigation works. He goes to page 2 but it does not show any new messages. He leaves only three posts and see no further.

Comment: You are passing offset 0 all the time in arguments, multiply your post per page and page no to get offset @JulianRouw

Comment: Have removed the offset 0. But still doesn't work

Comment: Possible that there will be only 3 posts, you dont remove offset, create a variable $offset=$paged*$pages. Make it dynamic.@JulianRouw

Comment: I have add this: $offset = $paged*$pages, butt there change nothing. There 5 posts but only the latest posts shows.

Comment: edit this, 'offset'=>$paged*$pages.@JulianRouw

Comment: Nothing changed. He shows only the latest three.

Comment: you can follow this one, http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-numeric-pagination-in-your-wordpress-theme/     and check in dashboard settings  post per page.

Comment: I've followed that tutorial but there nothing changed. I set the posts per page to 3, but also nothing changed. For the home I've set another own homepage with the posts.